# Sum of sum columns in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid java script grouping as follows

```
group: {
                        field: "ResourceName",
                        aggregates: [
                           { field: "WeekOneUtilization", aggregate: "sum" },
                            { field: "WeekTwoUtilization", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "WeekThreeUtilization", aggregate: "sum" },
                              { field: "WeekFourUtilization", aggregate: "sum" }
                        ]
                    },
                    aggregate: [{ field: "ProjectName", aggregate: "count" },
                                { field: "WeekOneUtilization", aggregate: "sum" },
                            { field: "WeekTwoUtilization", aggregate: "sum" },
                             { field: "WeekThreeUtilization", aggregate: "sum" },
                              { field: "WeekFourUtilization", aggregate: "sum" }]
```

I want to get Sum of sums of four weeks

the result is as follows
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is done in JavaScript so that's awesome... now you're the closest thing to god (of your grid) as you could be... so let's get to work.

1) Go to your datasource's model, and define some handy computed things there... for example.

```
var yourDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema:{
        model: {
            // Typical blah blah here
            id: 'your-id-field',
            fields: {
               // Typical field declaration blah blah
            },
            // This handy function will calculate
            // the sum of the 4 weeks in your row
            sumOfAllWeeks: function(){                    
               return this.get('WeekOneUtilization') + 
                      this.get('WeekTwoUtilization') + 
                      this.get('WeekThreeUtilization') + 
                      this.get('WeekFourUtilization');                 
            }
        }     
    }
});
```

2) Now you can just add this shiny brand new computed field into your aggregates configuration, the syntax is a bit different.

```
{ field: "sumOfAllWeeks()", aggregate: "sum" }
```

3) However, there is a bug (maybe its fixed now) if you want to just let kendo deal with aggregates of computed properties in your grid... he mistakenly tries to invoke your field name "sumOfAllWeeks()" as a function instead of an accumulator, unlike he does with a plain field. So in your grid, you have to use the templates as a function.

Let's illustrate this by  creating a new column for your computed, in your grid, like this...

```
 // Your grid fields declaration
 columns:[
     // Here you may have your columns declared,
     // as shown in your picture... so I save the blah blah
     // Now we declare a column for your computed.
     {
         field: 'sumOfAllWeeks()',
         aggregates: 'sum', 
         // This handles the group footer template
         groupFooterTemplate: function(data){
           return data['sumOfAllWeeks()'].sum;
         },
         // This handles the table footer template
         footerTemplate: function(data){
           return data['sumOfAllWeeks()'].sum;
         }
     }
 ]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for detail response, This code is adding a new column to all the rows and show the total of each line. What I really want is get only the sum of group footer values

Comment: @udaya726 well, it only shows a new column if you configure a column for that.. You don't have to put a column, I was showing you as an example so you can understand whats going on under the hood. Now how you render the stuff is up to you... but that means that you will have to access the result manually somewhere outside of your rendering "loop"...  You just configure the aggregate as I mentioned, and ask the DataSource to calculate it by using the method "aggregates" see  http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-aggregates

Comment: @udaya726 You could as well, put the groupFooterTemplate and footerTemplate functions... in any other and they will just work... because on each rendering pass, all values of the current row / group / footer are available through the parameter "data"

Comment: Thank you for the clear, detailed response. I've been having difficulty with this for awhile now and this cleared everything right up for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ClientTemplate` for this:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Total).ClientTemplate("#= WeekOneUtilization + WeekTwoUtilization + WeekThreeUtilization + WeekFourUtilization #");
```

Comment: @AdrianSalazar He may well have but not everyone searching for "Sum" and "kendo grid" will. Think of the bigger picture. :)